# HTC ONE - USB No longer recognized (but is charging)

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode, 4.3-jelly-bean, htc-one

I have a HTC ONE Google Edition on 4.3.  I was in the middle of transferring some files to my phone over USB when Windows 8 locked up and stopped responding.  Once I re-plugged my phone into the computer, the battery indicator is charging, but the USB connection never happens.

I've rebooted both the PC and the Phone.  I factory reset the phone. I plugged the phone into another windows PC and then my Linux box.  On the windows boxes, I get absolutely *nothing* -- no complaint of bad drivers.  Nothing in device manager.

In all cases, same thing.  A charge, but no connection.  Linux shows nothing on a `lsusb` command. `adb devices` returns nothing as well.

Ideas?  Thoughts?  Help? I'm fearful the USB connection in the phone went bad somehow.  Not sure how to debug the phone itself... As I cannot get to it's drive.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is not your case, but I've found an HTC ONE S with similar behavior (no USB sign of life, even in `dmesg` and `lsusb`) and the problem was the cable. It was like an USB cable but it was not a USB cable, only a power cable!

All the four pins were there but only two of them were connected, and instead of the USB logo it just had a lightning logo on both ends.

Now the question is: why does such a cable exist? How much can be saved not connecting the two data pins of a USB cable? 1 µ$ per cable?

Answer (score 1):

There are "charging only" USB cables.  Sounds like you might have one of those.

Also, try plugging into a different USB port.  Sometime on Windows, this will re-initialize the drivers.